# Anylogic - cannot use free function in wait block

Tags: java, anylogic

I am trying to use the wait block, but I simply can not use the free function, it keep geting error messages like
"Description: The method free(Agent) in the type Wait is not applicable for the arguments (). "

for the code:

```
Order.free();
```

or, "Description: Agent cannot be resolved to a variable."

for the code:

```
Order.free(Agent);
```

I tried to use freeAll to see if I was doing something wrong, and it was working perfectly, I have a looked on the other posts and couldn't find anything similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand Java and its syntax to understand what these messages want from you:

> "Description: The method free(Agent) in the type Wait is not applicable for the arguments (). "

The method wants an argument of type `Agent` so you cannot call it without an argument (i.e. `free()`)

> "Description: Agent cannot be resolved to a variable."

You called `free(Agent)` but this is also nonesense to Java. It wants an agent of type `Agent` so you need to provide an actual agent instance to it, and that agent needs to sit inside the Wait object.

Example: There are 5 agents of type `Agent` in your Wait object. If you want to free the first of these, you can call `wait.free(wait.get(0))`.

Or to free the last one, call `wait.free(wait.get(wait.size()-1))`